# Is font-size necessary for font CSS shorthand?

Tags: html, css

I want to use the `font` CSS shorthand to include all font properties (like `font-style`, `font-weight`, `font-size`, and so on).

It works if I use all properties.

```css
p.ex1 {
    font: 15px arial, sans-serif;
}

p.ex2 {
    font: italic bold 12px/30px Georgia, serif;
}
```

```html
<p class="ex1">This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph.</p>
<p class="ex2">This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph.</p>
```

But when I only have `font-weight` and `font-family`, it doesn't.

```css
p.ex1 {
    font: 900 Georgia, serif;
 }
```

```html
<p class="ex1">This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph.</p>
```

Why? Is it necessary to specify `font-size` when using the `font` CSS shorthand?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Yes.

From: [developer.mozilla.org/[...]/font](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font)

> Note: There are a few caveats when using the CSS font shorthand.
>   If these conditions are not met, the property is invalid and is entirely ignored.
>
> - Except when using a keyword, **it is mandatory to define the value of both the font-size and the font-family properties**.
> - Not all values of font-variant are allowed.
> - Only the values defined in CSS 2.1 are allowed, that is normal and small-caps.
> - Though not directly settable by font, the values of font-stretch, font-size-adjust and font-kerning are also reset to their initial values.
> - The order of the values is not completely free: font-style, font-variant and font-weight must be defined, if any, before the font-size value.
>     The line-height value must be defined immediately after the font-size, preceded by a mandatory /.
> - Finally the font-family is mandatory and must be the last value defined (inherit value does not work).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is nesscery to add font-size. Your can try this it will work.

```
p.ex1 {
    font: 900 Georgia, serif;
}
```

and the syntax for font is:

```
font: font-style font-variant font-weight font-size/line-height font-family|caption|icon|menu|message-box|small-caption|status-bar|initial|inherit;
```

Check it at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font.asp

Comment: Sorry i forget to add. Here is correct one p.ex1 { font: 900 12px Georgia, serif; }

Answer (score 0):

if you put it like

```
p.ex1 {
    font:  900 19px Georgia, serif;
 }
```

it will be work.

you just need size